# How to better justify this limit?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, discrete-mathematics

Suppose we have a set $\frac{2\pi}{L}\mathbb{Z}^{N}$ with $N\ge 1$ and we are given a function $f$ defined over $\mathbb{R}^{N}$. If $p = (p_{1},...,p_{N})\in \mathbb{R}^{N}$, let:
$$[p] := ([p_{1}],...,[p_{N}])$$
with $[x]$ denoting the integer part of $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $[x] = \inf\{z \in \mathbb{Z}: z \le x\}$. My professor wrote the following observations during class

1. For every $p \in \mathbb{R}^{d}$, $|[p]-p| < \frac{\pi}{L}\sqrt{N}$
2. Because of item 1. if we define $f=f([p])$ for each $p \in \mathbb{R}^{d}$ then $f([p]) \to f(p)$ as $L \to \infty$.

I have two questions. The first one: if $N=1$ then $|[p]-p| \le \frac{2\pi}{L}$, so for $N \ge 2$:
$$|[p]-p|^{2} = \sum_{i=1}^{N}|[p_{i}]-p_{i}|^{2} \le N\big{(}\frac{2\pi}{L}\big{)}^{2}$$
so 1. seems to be missing a factor of $\sqrt{2}$ according to this calculation. Is this a typo in his lecture notes or is there a better way to estimate $|[p]-p|$?

Second: item 2. works intuitively, but I wanted to prove it more than just with words and intuition. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $N=1$, if you have a point at equal distance from two consecutive points in $\frac{2\pi}{L}\mathbb{Z}$, then it will be at a distance $\frac{\pi}{L}$ from both points. Thus, for every $p \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $$|[p]-p| < \frac{\pi}{L}.$$

Provided that the function $f$ is continuous, indeed we have $f([p]) \to f(p)$ as $L \to \infty$ since $$|[p]-p| < \frac{\pi}{L}\sqrt{N}\to0$$ as $N\to\infty$. You don't need to say anything else.

Comment: Thanks! But I did not get the first point. If the point is in the "second half" of the interval (closer to the upper integer), wouldn't the distance be greater than $\frac{\pi}{L}$?

Comment: Then you look at the distance to that "upper integer", which is less than $\pi/L$.

Comment: Ah, Ok. But then the proper definition of $[p]$ would be the integer which is closest to $p$, right? I defined it differently, but this is probably why the results were not the same.

Comment: You are right. With your definition indeed we get the extra $2$. We should take (one of) the closest integers to avoid the extra $2$.